# adhoc distribution

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to do the following:

I have developed an iphone app. I want to send it to members of my team to test without having to put in their device ids into the apple developer program system. I have an Enterprise Apple Developer account.

How can I do this?

I just want to send members a link that they can click on their iphones to install the app without using Itunes or any other software.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

3 - Steps

1. Archive & Distribute for Enterprise (check the little box)
2. Create a simple web link on whatever site you want to use for this that is along the lines of: 
   `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.example.com/apps/myAppManifest.plist"`
3. Correct the app link in the "Manifest" plist file that xCode generated. Your manifest.plist will look like:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>   <key>items</key>
>   <array>
>       <dict>
>           <key>assets</key>
>           <array>
>               <dict>
>                   <key>kind</key>
>                   <string>software-package</string>
>                   <key>url</key>
>                   <string>https://www.example.com/apps/myApp.ipa</string>
>               </dict>
>           </array>
>           <key>metadata</key>
>           <dict>
>               <key>bundle-identifier</key>
>               <string>com.mycompany.myapp</string>
>               <key>bundle-version</key>
>               <string>1.0</string>
>               <key>kind</key>
>               <string>software</string>
>               <key>title</key>
>               <string>MyApp</string>
>           </dict>
>       </dict>
>   </array>
> </dict>
> </plist>
> ```

So, in summary: The weblink your users see will link to a plist that describes to the iDevice's OS, the software and where to download it.  Now, keep in mind that your enterprise license only allows you to distribute to individuals that are a part of your company.  It would be wise to make the website secure.

**UPDATE:** As of iOS 7.1 it is required that the manifest be hosted on an HTTPS link.  Just HTTP will not work anymore.

Comment: How to add app icon in plist file which can be displayed while downloading. see this http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad871e

Answer (score 1):

> A way to distribute application without asking user to copy
>   provisioning profile and application file to iTunes and then sync
>   iPhone with it.

Now, only thing that they need to do is to click on the link in e-mail on their phone, which will open website on device and there they can click to install application and profile on the iPhone.

http://blog.amarkulo.com/ad-hoc-profiles-and-application-distribution-via-web

Other reference :

http://support.twixlmedia.com/kb/epublisher-builder-application/how-do-i-create-the-distribution-provisioning-profile-for-my-ad-hoc-build