# How can I download Own App from Homepage?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I am looking for a way to load my own app to a website where i can download it. only for developer not for the app store, is this possible for the Student Program or only if i have the Enterprise Program?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're looking for, is it [testflight](http://testflightapp.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do Ad Hoc distribution. I will assume that you are enrolled as an Apple Developer in the Paid iOS program, you have downloaded and set up a developer certificate, and you have already registered the test device in the Apple Developer Center.

1. Create a Provisioning Profile for distributing Ad Hoc.
2. Set the Code Signing in your app to use this profile.
3. Create an Archive of your app for Ad Hoc with this new profile.
4. Take the Archive file and upload it to an ftp server. Make note of this location.
5. Create a plist file [like shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730126/adhoc-distribution), and use the location you noted in step 4.
6. Upload the plist file to the ftp.
7. Create a web page with a link to the plist file. It should trigger the download and will be successful on devices that are included in the provisioning profile you made in step 1.

Note: TestFlight is a popular alternative which has the added benefits of analytics, etc.

Comment: can i do it with a University Program?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to approve the devices that gets to install your app. Therefor it is **not** possible without the enterprise program.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it up to 100 devices (ad-hoc distribution),
but you have to know their device Ids which you have to enter into your application.

Further you can use TestFlight, too.